# How can I create an automatic ticking page to update my server database?

Tags: web

I'm very new to web development - basically I have a server that requires an operation run on it every minute. Someone suggested I make a simple web page that ticks and calls a script to do this whenever the counter reaches zero. Quite simply - how do I do this? Do I create an html page that calls some PHP?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It might be better to have a PHP code file that is ran by cron, rather than do the job while serving a page.

Answer (score 1):

Using cron is more simplier. Just install php-cli, type `crontab -e` command, add the following line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /full/path/to/your/script
```

But the thing you've described is also possible. Create `file.php` with the following content:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
<?php 
  //your code goes here
```

If you open this page in browser, php code is file will be executed. After 60 seconds, page will be reload automatically and your code will be executed again. But you have to get this page open in browser permanently. So, it's not a good way, but it fits as a fast temporary solution.

Comment: so what is cron exactly? and where do I install it to? thanks.

Comment: [Cron]|[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron] is a job schduller. It's usually installed by default on Linux servers, or you can install it from repository. You need to have ssh access to your server to use cron.